# Make <body> fill entire screen?

Tags: html, css, radial-gradients

I'm using a radial gradient as the background on my webpage, like so:

```css
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 100% 100%, 10, 90% 90%, 600, from(#ccc), to(#000));
```

It works, but when the content does not fill the whole page the gradient is cut off. How can I make the `<body>` element fill the entire page, always?

Comment: And `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` doesn't work?

Comment: That bit of css is applied to the body tag right? It works great for me in up-to-date Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/kdjFD/embedded/result/ . What browser are you testing?

Comment: No, `body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` doesn't work. I guess I have to apply it to `<html>` too.

Comment: Don't use the old -webkit- syntax. Use the official W3C syntax

Comment: @TimNguyen: This question was asked three years ago, when there was no browser support for that.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48503609/8620333 .. quite old as question but I don't really see an answer explaining the background propagation trick and why you only need `html{height:100%}`

Answer (score 279, accepted):

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It seems that all it takes is `html { height: 100%; }` actually.

Comment: Neither `html { height: 100%; }` nor `body { height: 100%; }` was enough for me (Opera included as a test) What worked best was `html, body { min-height: 100%; }` Using height instead of min-height left my background white w/o the background-color applied when I expanded some collapsible divs in the middle of my page. `min-height` fixed that.

Comment: Why is this issue happening only when using background : linear gradient and not with simple background

Comment: @ASEN Did you ever figure out why that is?

Comment: If it's still not working for anyone just change `100%` to `100vh`.

Comment: I know this is nearly a 10 year old question, but this accepted answer only works if your page doesn't fill the screen. Since I was fetching dynamic content it may or may not fill the screen, so I had to set html to height: 100% and body to min-height: 100% to get the desired effect.

Comment: When I change the height of a contained textarea, the overall height of the body changes (becomes much less than full screen).

Comment: I love you mate

Answer (score 35):

On our site we have pages where the content is static, and pages where it is loaded in with AJAX. On one page (a search page), there were cases when the AJAX results would more than fill the page, and cases where it would return no results. In order for the background image to fill the page in all cases we had to apply the following CSS:

```
html {
   margin: 0px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

body {
   margin: 0px;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

`height` for the `html` and `min-height` for the `body`.

Comment: Neither of them need `width: 100%;`.

Comment: because of display:block nature

Comment: also `margin: 0;` is enough, no need to specify which unit you use zero of

Comment: For me this almost works, but is a bit too high.

Answer (score 25):

As none of the other answers worked for me, I decided to post this as an answer for others looking for a solution who also found the same problem. Both the html and body needed to be set with `min-height` or the gradient would not fill the body height.

I found [Stephen P's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300/stephen-p) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721904/make-body-fill-entire-screen/30428430#comment21604517_5722111) to provide the correct answer to this.

```
html {
    /* To make use of full height of page*/
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[image: background filling body height]

When I have the html (or the html and body) height set to 100%,

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[image: background not filling body]

Comment: For me, this is a bit too high; the body overflows the page, in Chrome.

Answer (score 12):

I had to apply 100% to both html and body.

Answer (score 7):

The goal is to make the <body> element take up the available height of the screen.

If you don't expect your content to take up more than the height of the screen, or you plan to make an inner scrollable element, set

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

otherwise, you want <body> to become scrollable when there is more content than the screen can hold, so set

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

this alone achieves the goal, albeit with a possible, and probably desirable, refinement.

Removing the margin of <body>.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

there are two main reasons for doing so.

1. <body> reaches the edge of the window.
2. <body> no longer has a scroll bar from the get-go.

---

P.S. if you want the background to be a radial gradient with its center in the center of the screen and not in the bottom right corner as with your example, consider using something like

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using viewport (vh, vm) units of measure at the body level

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { min-height: 100vh; }

Use vh units for horizontal margins, paddings, and borders on the body and subtract them from the min-height value.

I've had bizarre results using vh,vm units on elements within the body, especially when re-sizing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the largely correct way, is to set css to this:

```
html
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The important parts of this are the same as the answer accepted six years ago, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

If you [have](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) a border or padding, then the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5722111/9295807)

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    border: solid red 5px;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

produces the imperfect rendering

[image: not good]

To get it right in the presence of a border or padding

[image: good]

use instead

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: solid red 5px;
    border-radius: 2em;
}
```

as [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972782/9295807) pointed out, although `overflow: hidden` is not needed.

(2018 - tested with Chrome 69 and IE 11)

Comment: Your answer is only relevant to you, and because you added a border to the `body` tag. Without that border, the `body` will fill exactly 100% of the viewport, you can see that with a background color for example. The correct answer to that question was accepted 7 years ago is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the solutions above and I'm not discrediting any of them, but in my case, they didn't work.

For me, the problem was caused because the `<header>` tag had a `margin-top` of 5em and the `<footer>` had a margin-bottom of 5em. I removed them and instead put some `padding` (top and bottom, respectively). I'm not sure if replacing the margin was an ideal fix to the problem, but the point is that, if the first and last elements in your `<body>` has some margins, you might want to look into it and remove them.

My `html` and `body` tags had the following styles

```
body {
  line-height: 1;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative; }

html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #3c3c3c; }
```