# CSS Background Image: Bottom of Page

Tags: html, css, image, layout, background-image

On my website, I have 3 background images applied to the `body` element (to give the impression of top, left and bottom borders) like so:

```
body {
    background: url('../image/body-x.gif') repeat-x 0 0,
                url('../image/body-x.gif') repeat-x 0 100%,
                url('../image/body-y.gif') repeat-y -280px 0;
    background-color: #47b48e;
}
```

This displays fine most of the time as the pages are quite long. But on shorter pages — such as the 404 template http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/asdfadsf — `body-x.gif` isn't sticking to the bottom of the page, like so:

[image]

I've tried adding the following code (I've read numerous times in the past that this is a common solution):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

But I can never get that to work. It still doesn't appear at the bottom, and instead it breaks it on the other pages. Such as on the About page, the bottom border image is overlapping the body copy like in this screengrab:

[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like the background-image is having a solid color so why not a background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
html, body { min-height: 100% }
```

From: [Make <body> fill entire screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721904/make-body-fill-entire-screen)

As an aside, what if you used a white top and bottom border on the body and only used the background image for the left white space? This would make the code simpler and cut down a couple unnecessary HTTP requests.

Comment: thanks! That seems to work nicely. Also I didn't even think of setting the top and bottom as borders! I've done that but now strangely I'm back with the original problem on the 404 page layout... it seemed to work fine with the images in there though and the `min-height` property!