# How to set background-color after end of body?

Tags: html, css

I have a dynamic generated table, and after table there is some space. I want to use background-color on that space too, but I can't. I tried use `html` and `body` selectors, also I tried to use `!important`, but it all don't work. You can see that space after that table:

[image: Dynamic generated table]

So, how can I use background-color on that space if `html` and `body` selectors don't work?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You will need to post a [mcve] in your question so that we can see what your HTML and CSS looks like

Comment: There are a lot of code there, but nothing affects on body or html. So, I don't know what code do you need ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do you need to just fill the whole page? Have you seen this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721904/make-body-fill-entire-screen

Comment: No, I don't fill the whole page - I need to background space after table. Yes, I saw that question - doesn't work for me

Comment: Try to inspect that space, maybe it's margin-bottom or padding-bottom. Please try to add more information so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I decided my problem. I added `padding-bottom` to my div, where table generated. It was space between `body` and `html` tags.

[image: Now you can see padding bottom]

UPD: I added a script. If table result = 0, then add to the div padding-bottom, and if > 0, then remove the padding-bottom

UPD #2: I added `min-height` for main `container-fluid` and it works well